# How to change created date of file on onedrive?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

How to change created date in C# Onedrive SDK?

```
string[] _scopes = { "onedrive.readwrite", "onedrive.appfolder" };
IOneDriveClient _OneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(_scopes);
await _OneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();

Item item = await _OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children["mydb.db"].Request().GetAsync();
Item newitem = new Item { CreatedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(2013, 2, 15, 2, 3, 4, 0, new TimeSpan()) };
var ri = await _OneDriveClient.Drive.Items[item.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(newitem);
```

Last line throws accessdenied exception.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Can't you just set the CreatedDateTime of the first item object and upload that, rather than creating an entire newItem object? If not, then you probably shouldn't be able to anyway. It could potentially break the sync mechanism of the API.

Comment: @ManoDestra, no. This case throws doublicatedid exception. Example [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632271.aspx#code-snippet-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the `createdDateTime` or `modifiedDateTime` properties as they're read-only system fields. However, you can set the values in the [`fileSystemInfo`](https://dev.onedrive.com/facets/filesysteminfo_facet.htm) facet to keep track of alternate timestamps. Be careful though, as these are the timestamps that are used by the sync client when manifesting the item locally, and so arbitrarily changing them can result in your synced files having their timestamps adjusted.

```
Item newitem = new Item
{
  FilesystemInfo = new FileSystemInfo
  {
    CreatedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(2013, 2, 15, 2, 3, 4, 0, new TimeSpan()),
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm also trying to modify the creation and last modifed attributes. It seems trying to update these fields via FileSystemInfo does not seem to have any effect on OneDrive for business accounts. Any more ideas?